# RabbitMQ pull vs push consume

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, mjpeg

I'm streaming video (mjpeg) from my RaspberryPi to the browser via cloud proxy. I pass video frame-by-frame to rabbitmq queue, the queue is being listened by the springboot app which displays the video on a web page.

Pull model works (not fine, slow, but works) - I call a "getter" in an infinite loop and write payload bytes to output stream. However, when I'm trying push model - passing a lambda-based callback that is to be invoked every time when a new message appears in the queue, I'm getting troubles to write to outputstream.

Pull model:

```
@SneakyThrows
@GetMapping("/stream")
protected void stream(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--BoundaryString");
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    while(true) {
        GetResponse payload = channel.basicGet(VIDEO_STREAMING_QUEUE_NAME, true);

        if (payload == null) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } else {
            byte[] body = payload.getBody();
            outputStream.write((
                    "--BoundaryString\r\n" +
                            "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n" +
                            "Content-Length: " +
                            body.length +
                            "\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
            outputStream.write(body);
            outputStream.write(TWO_LINE_BYTES);
            //outputStream.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Push model:

```
@SneakyThrows
@GetMapping("/stream")
public void stream(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--BoundaryString");
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
        byte[] body = delivery.getBody();
        outputStream.write((
                "--BoundaryString\r\n" +
                        "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n" +
                        "Content-Length: " +
                        body.length +
                        "\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
        outputStream.write(body);
        outputStream.write(TWO_LINE_BYTES);
        //outputStream.flush();
    };

    channel.basicConsume(VIDEO_STREAMING_QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
}
```

Exception log output:

```
2022-02-13 19:16:36.931 ERROR 5601 --- [pool-1-thread-4] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : Consumer com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel$2@56526586 (amq.ctag-xo0rULncjobFFPw1NssU_w) method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel(amqp://mmkkhpcj@34.252.237.144:5671/mmkkhpcj,1) threw an exception for channel AMQChannel(amqp://mmkkhpcj@34.252.237.144:5671/mmkkhpcj,1)

org.apache.coyote.CloseNowException: Failed write
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:549) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:194) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:615) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:688) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:366) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at bobby.remote.controller.VideoController.lambda$stream$0(VideoController.java:66) ~[main/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel$2.handleDelivery(AutorecoveringChannel.java:588) ~[amqp-client-5.14.0.jar:5.14.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149) ~[amqp-client-5.14.0.jar:5.14.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104) ~[amqp-client-5.14.0.jar:5.14.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

Where *bobby.remote.controller.VideoController.lambda$stream$0(VideoController.java:66)* points to **outputStream.write(body);** line. It looks like outputStream is not available from DeliverCallback lambda.

Any ideas why push model doesn't work? What is missing to make it work?

**UPD**
By the way, writing to outputStream works even without flushing it. Are there any reasons to flush or not to flush it?

Answer (score 0):

I could not see your whole code and I recommend the following steps:

1. Follow this pattern:

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
string consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume("queuename", true, consumer);
```

2. Please also use consumerTag cancel, close cannel and connection in your code, as shown below:

```
channel.BasicCancel(consumerTag);
channel.Close();
connection.Close();
```